# Pause CountDownTimer and resume automatically after 10 seconds

Tags: android, countdowntimer

In my application, i have 1 imageview. I want to pause the countdowntimer for 10 seconds when and resume "automatically" after 10secs. How can i do that? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Note: I am a newbie in android programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            //your code goes here
        }
    }, delaytime,timeperiodtorun);
```

Comment: put delay time to 10000

Comment: I'm sorry but i have another question. I already have a countdowntimer my question is, where should i put that? I am confused. and what should i put insid the public void run?

Answer (score 0):

Schedule a countdown until a time in the future, with regular notifications on intervals    along the way. 
 Example of showing a 10 second countdown in a text field:[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

```
  new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {  
       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }
       public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start()
```

Comment: On my app,i have 30sec countdowntimer. I have 1 imageview and what i want to do when it is click is that it should pause the countdowntimer for 10sec. and resume "automatically". how could i possibly do that?

Comment: Its feasible way is click imagview cancel a running timer and start timer again.

Comment: i set an onclicklistener to my imageview and put coundowntimer.cancel(); only. i have an idea on how should i create this but i dont know how to code it. 
i read something like crating a thread but i dont know how to do that. please explain further. If its okay, please include some codes so that i could easily understand.